# Sets where functions can be discontinuous

Tags: calculus, analysis

Consider functions of the form $f: (0,1) \to \Bbb{R}$, and let $D(f)$ denote the set of points where $f$ is not continuous.

Can we get a function for which $D(f)=\emptyset$?

And can we get a function for which $D(f)=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what $D(f)$ looks like for any specific functions (ex. $f(x)=x$)?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: consider $F(x) = \delta(x-1/2)$

Comment: I thought that $D(f)$ denotes the set of points of continuity, that was why I answered the question. Now that I know what it is: can you really not think of such examples? It seems to me that you didn't bother trying to solve the homework.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A function for which $D(f) = \emptyset$ is a function which has no discontinuous points on $(0,1)$. Can you think of ANY functions that might look like this?

For the second one, what functions are discontinuous at points? The easiest way to do this is to make a function that just isn't defined there. How can you make a function not defined at a point?